# Codeigniter, characters # in url

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have a search form on my website and when i'm going on this page, i have some strange characters in my url, like #.U7BSlfl_uSo and i don't know why ?

I think about php session flag but i'm not sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be generated by PHP, but php itself cannot get the URL hash. It's probably set by some of your javascript included in your page.

Can you provide a demo of your form?

Answer (score 0):

This type of # characters are generating by some api used by our page or site sometimes like Google translator,Google analytics.